# getting value undefined into function, the function is declare into another js file and used inside the component in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have one js file called test.js and i have one function inside it

```
export const a =(data)=>{
                 console.log(data)
}
```

and i have a functional component called File.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {a} from "./test";

let data = "hello"

function File() {
useEffect(()=> {a(data)},[]}
  return ( <div>something</div>)
}

export default File;
```

and i get output in console.log is undefined, i should get "hello". i dont understand what the problem please help me

Comment: Assuming you meant `useEffect(()=> {a(data)},[])` (ends with `)` not `}`) I [can't reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-sunset-l1w2sw?file=/src/App.js) this. Please make a [mre] so we can help debug your issue.

Comment: It's just a typo. Vote to close please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the `useEffect()` wrong bracket type issue the code should work just fine:

#### File.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { a } from './test';

let data = 'hello';

function File() {
  useEffect(() => a(data), []);
  return <div>something</div>;
}

export default File;
```

Here I've implemented it in a minimal code environment, and it is printing `hello` as intended.

### Environment Link

[StackBlitz Virtual Environment Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2gnoap?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/App.js)